# Error with C++ module code containing a class hierarchy involving a template class and a friend class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20, visual-studio-2022, c++-modules

I'm getting a 'base class undefined' error in some module-based C++ code I'm writing.  I've reduced it to the following MCVE.  The non-module equivalent compiles fine.
I don't understand why the modularized code here fails.  Please could someone explain why I'm getting the error and how, if possible, to fix it.

Here's the module interface unit -

```
// mcve.ixx

export module mcve;

export class X
{
    friend class F; // (1)
};

export
template<typename T>
class A
{
};

export class B: public A<X>
{
};

// (2)
export class F: public B
{
};
```

and the cpp file showing where the compiler error is reported.

```
// main.cpp

import mcve;

int main()
{
    // X x;     // (3)
    // A<X> ax; // (4)
    // F f;     // (5)
    B b;        // error C2504: 'B': base class undefined
}
```

Interestingly, removing either of the `friend class F;` at (1) or the whole `class F` declaration at (2) results in successful compilation.
Equally, uncommenting either of (3), (4) or (5) also works.

This is with Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 v17.2 (Platform toolset v143)(CL version 19.32.31328) and either `/std:c++20` or `/std:c++latest`.

Comment: You mean uncommenting 3, 4 or 5 while 2 remains enabled or do you comment out?

Comment: Each in isolation, so making any single one of the 1-5 changes works.

Comment: "I don't understand why the modularized code here fails". Compiler bugs in a half-baked implementation of a half-baked language feature.

Comment: Tried on online-GDB, but that doesn't seem to support modules at all so far (or I did something wrong there...). Others I couldn't test either, didn't allow multiple files, my local MinGW seems too outdated, too, to support modules, so cannot provide comparison for now. MSVC is not really famous for being standard compliant, might easily be an inconsistency to the standard (-> bug).

Comment: I didn't want to jump to the compiler bug conclusion without asking those more expert than I to point out if it was in fact my understanding that was buggy.

Comment: Yeah it's definitely not just MSVC. Apparently, I can't even write `export module mcve;` without reliably crashing my IDE. It's up to date and uses a recent version of libclang (13 or 14) for code analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been [confirmed](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Error-with-C-module-code-containing-a-/10049061#T-N10452377) as a MSVC compiler bug and fixed.
The response on Developer Community currently doesn't say which version it was fixed in but it works in 17.7.2.